# Why is the 'Done' button disabled in the Card.io payment view controller -- even in the sample apps?

Tags: ios, card.io

I'm using the card.io SDK for iOS, and everything works brilliantly -- EXCEPT:

The "Done" button is disabled.  It's disabled in my app where I integrated card.io, but it's also disabled in both the Objective C and the Swift sample apps that come with the SDK.

[image: Done button disabled]

For a while I felt like I misunderstood how to use it from the user's perspective, but after I scan a card and enter an expiration and a CVV the "Done" button should be enabled, right?

The image that I posted is [the Objective-C SampleApp](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp).  The [Swift SampleApp](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp-Swift) behaves in the exact same way.  And so does my app, where I successfully integrated card.io.

I'm using XCode version 7.2 (7C68).  This is consistent between three different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Aha!  The expiration date matters.  Didn't realize it was validating that.

Okay I feel dumb now.  If anybody else ends up here, just make sure that the fake expiration date that you're typing during development is in the future.

Feature suggestion: Slightly more clear UX on the validation could help newbies.

Thanks for open-sourcing card.io, it's really awesome.

Comment: Yep, that's it... Acceptable dates are approximately within now + 15 yrs.